# Make 3D array with 1D arrays with zero padding depending on index of 1D array numpythonically

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider the following 1D arrays

```
a=np.arange(3)+9
b=np.arange(3)+5
```

currently I am initializing the new 3d array by using

```
n=4
cols=3
k=np.vstack((a,b,a*b,np.zeros((n,cols)),a,b,a,a,b**2,np.zeros((n,cols)),a*2,a)).T.reshape(-1,2,n+5)
```

where a and b will always be the same shape

which results in

```
array([[[  9.,   5.,  45.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   9.,   5.],
        [  9.,   9.,  25.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  18.,   9.]],

       [[ 10.,   6.,  60.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  10.,   6.],
        [ 10.,  10.,  36.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  20.,  10.]],

       [[ 11.,   7.,  77.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  11.,   7.],
        [ 11.,  11.,  49.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  22.,  11.]]])
```

How would i use a similar technique, also without a for loop, to change the zero padding to the following:

```
array([[[  9.,   5.,  45.,   9.,   5.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  9.,   9.,  25.,  18.,   9.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]],

       [[ 10.,   6.,  60.,   0.,   0.,  10.,   6.,   0.,   0.],
        [ 10.,  10.,  36.,   0.,   0.,  20.,  10.,   0.,   0.]],

       [[ 11.,   7.,  77.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  11.,   7.],
        [ 11.,  11.,  49.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  22.,  11.]]])
```

Comment: Sorry n is meant to be 4 and cols is 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to assign those array values into a zeros initialized array given the column indices -

```
out = np.zeros((3,2,9),dtype=bool)
vals = np.array([[a,b,a*b,a,b],[a,a,b**2,2*a,a]])
out[np.arange(3)[:,None],:, idx] = vals.T
```

Sample run -

```
In [448]: a
Out[448]: array([ 9, 10, 11])

In [449]: b
Out[449]: array([5, 6, 7])

In [450]: out
Out[450]: 
array([[[  9.,   5.,  45.,   9.,   5.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  9.,   9.,  25.,  18.,   9.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]],

       [[ 10.,   6.,  60.,   0.,   0.,  10.,   6.,   0.,   0.],
        [ 10.,  10.,  36.,   0.,   0.,  20.,  10.,   0.,   0.]],

       [[ 11.,   7.,  77.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  11.,   7.],
        [ 11.,  11.,  49.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  22.,  11.]]])
```

Comment: Would this work even when there is not only a vector a but other vectors such as k=np.vstack((a,b,b,np.zeros((n,cols)),d,e,f,g,h,np.zeros((n,cols)),a,a)).T.reshape(-1,2,n+5)

Comment: @Alex With all of `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h` being of the same shapes?

Comment: Yes, all the same

Comment: @Alex I am not exactly clear on the expected output on such a case. Could you edit the question with those?

Comment: Does that make it clearer? Often i try to use the simplest variable so that it makes it easier to see but sometimes that can make it look like a different problem all together. Sorry for the confusion.